# Manipulating data from array of objects inside object to array of objects inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to manipulate data, and I'd need a solution for this

Tried mapping in different ways, but none of them worked.

This is the input data:

```
   data_input = {
    2000: [{
            _id: 0,
            name: "Jeff",
            value: 130,
            year: 2000
        },
        {
            _id: 1,
            name: "Bill",
            value: 30,
            year: 2000
        }
    ],
    2001: [{
            _id: 0,
            name: "Jeff",
            value: 20,
            year: 2001
        },
        {
            _id: 1,
            name: "Bill",
            value: 100,
            year: 2001
        }
    ]
 }
```

Here is the expected result:

```
   data_output = [{
        year: 2000,
        year_data: [{
                _id: 0,
                name: "Jeff",
                value: 130
            },
            {
                _id: 1,
                name: "Bill",
                value: 30
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        year: 2001,
        year_data: [{
                _id: 0,
                name: "Jeff",
                value: 20
            },
            {
                _id: 1,
                name: "Bill",
                value: 100
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**Object.entries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

***Here idea is :-***

- with `object.entries` get the key value from object and map on them to change it to needed format
- `Key` is used as `year` property in desired structure and `value` is used as `year_data`

```js
let data = {2000: [{ _id: 0, name: "Jeff", value:130, year: 2000 }, { _id: 1, name: "Bill", value:30, year: 2000 } ] , 2001 : [{ _id: 0, name: "Jeff", value: 20, year: 2001 }, {_id:1, name: "Bill", value: 100, year: 2001 } ]}

let final = Object.entries(data).map(([year, year_data]) => ({ year, year_data: year_data.map(({year,...rest})=>rest)}))

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the values and destructure the year from the rest object.

```js
var data_input = { 2000: [{ _id: 0, name: "Jeff", value: 130, year: 2000 }, { _id: 1, name: "Bill", value: 30, year: 2000 }], 2001: [{ _id: 0, name: "Jeff", value: 20, year: 2001 }, { _id: 1, name: "Bill", value: 100, year: 2001 }] },
    result = Object
        .values(data_input)
        .map(a => ({ year: a[0].year, year_data: a.map(({ year, ...rest }) => rest) }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
 data_input = {
    2000: [{
            _id: 0,
            name: "Jeff",
            value: 130,
            year: 2000
        },
        {
            _id: 1,
            name: "Bill",
            value: 30,
            year: 2000
        }
    ],
    2001: [{
            _id: 0,
            name: "Jeff",
            value: 20,
            year: 2001
        },
        {
            _id: 1,
            name: "Bill",
            value: 100,
            year: 2001
        }
    ]
 }

var output = Object.keys(data_input).map(item => {
  let year_data = data_input[item].map(data => {
    delete data.year
    return data
  });
  return {
    year: item,
    year_data:year_data
  }
});

console.log(output);
```